# Resize the window based on the content

Tags: c#, wpf, size, autoresize

I tried different things but without success

I have to size the window relative to the dynamic numbers of tiles (MahApps.Metro) but only in height, once the height exceeded of my screen I put a scroolbar

In my window I have for the moment:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="EpiTUILE.MainWindow"
                  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                  xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
Title="EpiTUILE" Height="270" Width="400" ShowMaxRestoreButton="False" ShowCloseButton="False" 
Top="0" Loaded="MetroWindow_Loaded" Icon="Alerte.png" Closing="MetroWindow_Closing" 
MouseMove="MetroWindow_MouseMove" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" MouseEnter="MetroWindow_MouseEnter" 
StateChanged="MetroWindow_StateChanged" WindowStyle="None" UseLayoutRounding="True"
AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent" WindowState="Minimized">

<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="TileStyle" TargetType="Controls:Tile">
        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDown" Handler="OnTileClick" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="380" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="70" />
        <Setter Property="TitleFontSize" Value="10" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Height="Auto">
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="MyScrollViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="1" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ScrollViewer.FlowDirection="LeftToRight" >
        <WrapPanel Name="PanelTile" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="Auto" >
        </WrapPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

I then build my tiles in code behind:

```
PanelTile.Children.Clear();
for (int i = 0; i < _nbrTile; i++)
{
    Tile _tile = new Tile();
    _tile.HorizontalTitleAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
    _tile.Title = i.ToString();
    _tile.Style = this.FindResource("TileStyle") as Style;
    _tile.Content = "Type Alerte " + i;

    PanelTile.Children.Add(_tile);
}
```

Comment: Did you try to set the SizeToContent property of the window to Height?

Comment: Of course, but it does not work.

If I take for example: 5 tiles, it shows me the 5 tiles without scrollbar but I have a window that takes the full height of my screen while my window should take a little more than half of the screen screen

Comment: Ok, i find with a stack pannel and SizeToContent property of the window but I can not display the scrollbar

Comment: it's ok with             _scrollViewerTitle.Content = _panelTitle;
            MyGrid.Children.Add(_scrollViewerTitle);

Comment: So what is your current issue?

Comment: Yes, it's ok for me. thanks

Comment: Should I post an answer?